# groovy capture stdout last line

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have issues extracting stdout to get only the result, last(second line).

i have jenkins pipeline using groovy script which executes the following:

```
    stage('Generate'){
       stdout = bat([
           returnStdout: true, 
           script: 'C:/folder/generate.exe --environment %ENVIRONMENT% --optionalproperties %OPTIONALPROPS%',
           encoding: 'UTF-8'
       ]).trim();
```

if i pass echo stdout, to capture what this command generated, i get stdout as -

C:\folder2\folder2>C:/folder1/generate.exe --environment PROD --optionalproperties something
12345678

So my result is in new line, 12345678. I need to capture only this.

I used before to do this with:
result = stdout.readLines().drop(1).split(" ")
and i was getting just the 12345678. But it stopped working somehow.

I managed to find a workaround with this:

result =  stdout.reverse().take(8).reverse()

which takes last 8 numbers and extracts them. But it's not good solution as i might have more or less amount of numbers generated, so i need a proper way to extract it.

Any advise guys what i could try else as i dont get why readLines() fails to get me any result, though the batch command didnt change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In other words you need to get last word of output.
So you can do:

```
result = stdout.tokenize().last()
```

Answer (score 0):

**def last_text = .tokenize().last()**

echo ${last_text}  //for printing last text value

Comment: Hi Vipul, please try and provide some context surrounding your answers so that they can be better understood - code on it's own is almost always an insufficient answer to explain what should be done and why.